# Postgres - How updates in one session (in if-then block) to be immediately visible for other sessions

Tags: postgresql

I have a function in PG which has if-then block, something like this

```
if <condition> then
         ...
         update mytab set col1=true;
         <some long time operation>
end if;
```

By function call I expect that when I update mytab and proceed with the long operation, then other sessions will see that mytab.col1 is true (I want to use it like a flag).

But what happens is that mytab is updated, but it is visible only for this session. The other sessions see that mytab.col1 is still false.
 First after finishing of the long operation (and the whole if-then block), then other session see that mytab.col1 is true.

How to make this update immediately visible (in Oracle f.i. commit will do the trick).

Comment: Why don't you break up the "large operation" that apparently is not a single transaction into different functions that carry out one transaction each?

Comment: Hi, I can't break up the longop, because it is actually one transaction - refresh materialized view. What I want is somehow to check are there in the moment any mat views refresh processes in the database. I could check pg_stat_activity, but I can't see there 'refresh materialized view' command, but the whole function.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, since the complete body of a function runs within one transaction.

The only workaround is to open a second database connection with [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html) and 
execute (and commit) your update there.